# Local Declaration "x" hides instance variable xcode warning

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, instance

I've been have trouble understand this problem. If I change the variable name fifthViewController  the error goes away but the view controller doesn't load.

Lost. Once again it's probably something simple.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
{
FifthViewController *fifthViewController = [[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthView" bundle:nil];

fifthViewController.transactionID = transactionID;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fifthViewController animated:NO]; 
[fifthViewController release];
 }
```

Comment: I could be more specific in my answer if you post a more complete implementation file.

Comment: Pretty clear error message. Try using e.g. FifthViewController *myFifthViewController.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This means the variable `fifthViewController` is named the same as something else in your class implementation. If you mean to use that variable, drop the `FifthViewController*` type declaration off the first line; otherwise, change the name `fifthViewController` everywhere it appears in that method.